# Why does shadow dom hide html elements in inspect mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom

[image: shadow-dom hiding html elemtns]

Shadow Dom doesn't reveal the source code on this website, monday.com. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please explain what you expect to see here

Comment: It's not hiding it. It tells you exactly what it is when you expand it. And you can double click on reveal if you want. If you really want to see what's under the hood use Edge, because IE & Edge don't support anything ever (exaggeration). Shadow DOM is not Edge compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The `<head>` and `<body>` that are showing in the `<shadow>` are references to the real `<head>` and `<body>` that are outside of the `<shadow>`.

Consider that the entries in the `<shadow>` are like named slots and they are embedding a reference of the real `<head>` and `<body>` into the `<shadow>` without copying them there.